# Inspect Element in lynx

Tags: javascript, browser, lynx

I am looking for an element inspector in lynx web browser. I want to extract some data from the web site. It involves changing the url of the link a bit every-time and fetching information. I tried using a macro in firefox but couldn't figure out how to write a for-loop kind of thing. So I am now trying lynx. Is it possible to do inspect element in lynx as we do in standard web browsers like mozilla firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lynx doesn't construct a DOM (this is one of the main things holding people back from adding serious JS support to it), so it holds nothing in memory that you can inspect.

Comment: Can you then please suggest me something which will help me accomplish the task?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic for Stackoverflow, but there should be useful libraries for any programming language you care to name.

Comment: I tried using javascript but couldn't access the anchor using its id as it was in a tree-view.